# Rename empty column in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Hello I am trying to create a function that will take in a dataframe, and return to me the number of unique values for a given column. I have managed to get the dataset into an output format I like, but I can't seem to rename one of the columns(as indicated in the output). Do you have any thoughts on how to do this?I have tried supplying column names in the as.data.frame, and that has not worked. After looking at the dataframe, it appears that it should be using the fix.empty names argument, but even after supplying it, it still seems to give me an empty column name(see output). I think it may have something to do with this fix, but I'm not sure...http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Data-frame-printing-buglet-when-multiple-empty-column-names-td4718088.html Thanks for your time.

```
#Function to Find unique values in a dataframe
library(knitr)
library(formattable)
findUniqueVals <- function(df) {
  poop <- sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)))
  poop <- as.data.frame(poop, fix.empty.names==TRUE)
  kable(poop)
  #formattable::formattable(poop)
}
findUniqueVals(patientdata)
#should have a column header not just empty string
Output:
|             | poop|
|:------------|----:|
|patient.ID   |    4|
|patient.name |    4|
|Adm.Date     |    4|
|diabetes     |    2|
|p.status     |    3|

#testdata
patient.ID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
patient.name <-c("pat1", "pat2", "pat3","pat4")
Adm.Date <- as.POSIXct(c('2010-10-11','2008-3-25','2016-4-23','2011-6-12'))
diabetes <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type2")
p.status <- c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
patientdata <- data.frame(patient.ID,patient.name,Adm.Date,diabetes,p.status)
```

Comment: What about e.g. `colnames(poop)[1] <- "Column 1"` ?

Comment: I get an error with "> colnames(poop)[1] <- "test"
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "test") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions".

Comment: Hello. @Billywob is right: `colnames()` does the job normally. If it doesn't for you, try to give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that throws the same error you get. This will improve the chance you get a full answer.

Comment: I don't have access to any packages right now so I can't run your example. Could it be that the first column is not an actual column but rather the row names? What happens when you run `dim(poop)` ?

Comment: That is actually  `rownames` for your dataframe and not a column

Comment: dim (poop)says it is null

Comment: this was one of the other errors I got which seems to prove there is an empty string there: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(" ", "Row Name", "Count")) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent 
3.
`colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c(" ", "Row Name", "Count")) 
2.
kable(poop, col.names = c("Row Name", "Count")) 
1.
findUniqueVals(order_table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code I came up with for those that are interested:

I understand that not everyone is a huge fan of the global assignment via the <<-, but I think it simplifies the inputs to the function to make the code more readable.

```
createmydf <- function(df) {
  #Create DF with column names
  #1.- Fill Data Frame Row name column with a vector of Column names
  #2.- Fill TCount with a vector of counts
  #3.- Display results using formattable
  x <<- data.frame("Row Name"= numeric(0), "TCount"=numeric(0))
  result <- sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)))

  #Now Create the Row names
  for (i in 1:length(colnames(df))) {
    x[i,1] <<- (names(result[i]))
    x[i,2] <<- result[[i]]
  }
  return(x)
}
```

The proper results will be outputted as follows:

```
     Row.Name TCount
1   patient.ID      4
2 patient.name      4
3     Adm.Date      4
4     diabetes      2
5     p.status      3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are not returning any object using the function, and the the `poop` object inside is a 5 by 1 data frame. To see this use e.g:

```
findUniqueVals <- function(df) {
  poop <- sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)))
  poop <- as.data.frame(poop)
  #formattable::formattable(poop)
  #kable(poop) commented this out because I don't have access to the package

  return(poop)   # returning the actual object
}

poop <- findUniqueVals(patientdata)
dim(poop)
colnames(poop) 
rownames(poop)
```

If you want the output from `rownames(poop)` as an actual column you could simply append within the function.

Comment: When I try to change the row names I get this error: row.names(poop) <- c("test1","Test2")
Error in `rownames<-`(x, value) : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions